# Get zero coverage with nyc and playwright

Tags: testing, code-coverage, v8, playwright, nyc

I'm struggling to set up coverage correctly using Playwright. It reports 0 coverage in all files (except the test files themselves, if I include them).

I'm getting inspiration from https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-coverage and https://github.com/bgotink/playwright-coverage/blob/main/src/fixtures.ts. Our project is a monorepo where tests in a folder `e2e-tests/` run end to end tests on servers contained in other adjacent folders, e.g. `frontend/`.

The current setup is using a `page` fixture like so in each test-file:

```js
// frontend.spec.ts
import { test, expect } from "../fixtures";

test("something", ({ page ) => {
    // Do test stuff with page
});
```

where the fixture is defined as

```js
// fixtures/page.ts
import { Page, TestInfo } from "@playwright/test";

const pageWithCoverage = async (
  { page, browserName }: { page: Page; browserName: string },
  use: (page: Page) => Promise<void>,
  testInfo: TestInfo
) => {
  if (!page.coverage) throw new Error(`Could not collect coverage with browser "${browserName}"`);

  console.log(" Collecting coverage");
  await page.coverage.startJSCoverage();
  await use(page);
  await page.coverage.stopJSCoverage();
};

export default pageWithCoverage;
```

To collect coverage I run

```
npx nyc --all --cwd ".." --include "**/frontend/**/*  --nycrc-path e2e-tests/.nycrc npm t
```

where the relevant part concerning the file structure is:

```
 --all --cwd ".." --include "**/frontend/**/*"
```

I'm using a `.nycrc` file containing [`nyc-config-tsx`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nyc-config-tsx) in order to instrument tsx files:

```json
// .nycrc
{
  "extends": "nyc-config-tsx",
  "all": true
}
```

Can you tell what the issue is?

The frontend is built using `next`.

I get similar results storing results to files using `v8toIstanbul` and running `npx nyc report`

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem today, at pretty much the one-year anniversary of your issue. I found this question hoping it had an answer...

Anyway, here's what made it work for me.

The [repo you linked](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nyc-config-tsx) oddly had no effect for me. It still didn't properly register jsx-type code that you'd find in .tsx files, so every report came without any .tsx files having been instrumented by `nyc`.

I found the issue to be on [this line](https://github.com/istanbuljs/istanbuljs/blob/master/packages/nyc-config-typescript/index.js#L7) of that package because if I changed it to include `jsx` like so:

`parserPlugins: parserPlugins.concat('typescript', 'jsx')`

in the file inside node_modules, then it worked.

So the fix became to re-make that file in my own project, and then extend it in the `nyc` config file.

```
// nyc-config.js

'use strict';
const { parserPlugins } = require('@istanbuljs/schema').defaults.nyc;
module.exports = {
  cache: false,
  parserPlugins: parserPlugins.concat('typescript', 'jsx'),
};
```

```
// .nycrc.json

{
  "extends": "./nyc-config.js",
  "reporter": ["cobertura", "lcov"],
  "all": true,
  "include": [
    "**/*.tsx",
    "**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    // ...
  ],
}
```

After that, `nyc` was able to instrument .tsx files and check them for coverage.

EDIT:

My project uses Vite to build, as opposed to OP's `next`, and it's important that the server you run tests against enables coverage tracking.

For instance, in `playwright.config.ts`, you'd have

```
webServer: {
  command: 'VITE_COVERAGE=true npx nyc npm run start',
  port: 5173,
},
```

if you were using Vite.